# Generate additional ISO date format key-value json pair for java.util.Date object using GSON java

Tags: java, json, gson, isodate

I am using google's GSON library to convert java objects to its corresponding JSON format. I am serializing an object, it gives JSON output as :

```
{"fname":"sunil","lname":"sharma","id":1,"dob":"2015-10-07T10:15:54+05"}
```

In above JSON format dob is in ISO format.

**What I want is :**

When ever GSON find any Date type field, it should parse it as normal java format and in ISO8601 format also :

```
{
    "fname": "sunil",
    "lname": "sharma",
    "id": 1,
    "dob": {
        "value": "Oct 7, 2015 10:15:54 AM",
        "iso8601": "2015-10-07T06:09:54+00:00"
    }
}
```

How can i achieve it ?

Comment: Might I ask *why* you want that? The result looks more complicated to read as a human, and definitely more complicated to handle for whatever's parsing the data later. If it's just "I find the first format easier to read" I suggest you simply get used to ISO-8601. That's just a matter of time...

Comment: you need a custom date serializer: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Serializer

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right but I want it in all these format. My requirement and design need both the formats.

Comment: That hasn't asked my question of *why* you need it at all... I would strongly urge you to reconsider your design.

Comment: @wero Dear can you please share me one example. How can i create another key-value paid while parsing using serializers ??

Comment: @JonSkeet So what you are suggesting ?? only ISO-8601 format or normal one ??? But I case I strongly have to do it then ?

Comment: @JonSkeet Bro actually the reason behind is that the normal format is for display purpose. And ISO-8601 is for developer while updating / inserting data to database. DB only accept ISO-8601 format.

Comment: That's a terrible reason. Don't confuse data transmission/storage with display. You can do a lot better than displaying the Java default representation - but you should do that by parsing the ISO format and then formatting it *when you need to display it*. That allows you to format it in context - in the user's locale, for example.

Comment: @SunilSharma You are going against all odds. Your approach is faulty and Jon points out the right approach.

Comment: @JonSkeet and Michael guys. I understood your point.  Now I just want to clear my concept. Forget about the date field only , suppose there is a another field A and i want to add another key-value pair while parsing by GSON. Then how can I do that ?? Would you guys suggest me some workaround instead of suggesting me design. Let leave the design and approach to architect.

Comment: Firstly, this isn't parsing - it's formatting. (It's important to get the difference right for communication.) Next, if it's not a date field, it could be an entirely different solution, as then you wouldn't be using a custom date serializer... Have you read https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Serializer thoroughly?